# I am trying to package my java application from command line using jar command

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I am trying to package my java application from command line using jar command. But Everytime I am getting messgae "Access is denied".

```
c:\Users\user\Documents> jar cvfm app.jar manifest.txt appfolder/* 
Access is denied
```

Then I simply just executed "jar" command and I got the same error again i.e Access is Denied.

```
c:\Users\user\Documents> jar
```

Comment: have u tried Run as administrator

Comment: Your problem is too dependent on your system configuration. Without more details we cannot help you. Try re-installing your JDK?

Comment: @ rupesh_padhye yes I have tried to run it with admin priviliges.

Comment: This is not a java problem.